# Screen Grab for object recognition using Tensorflow and python

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision

guys, I would like to know how to use a screen-grabbed image then classify the data and draw boxes around objects using Tensorflow, I want the screen grabbing and classification to be done fast enough to be continuous and simulate a video. I have done this before using a cascase haras method. I have a working tensorflow model with a custom inference graph all working with webcam and video. I would like to know how to alter the following code to read the relavent data from an image instead of a video:

```
def from_img(img):
ret, frame = video.read()   <-- i want to change this line to read this data from the image
frame_expanded = np.expand_dims(frame, axis=0)

# Perform the actual detection by running the model with the image as input
(boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
    [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
    feed_dict={image_tensor: frame_expanded})

# Draw the results of the detection (aka 'visulaize the results')
vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
    frame,
    np.squeeze(boxes),
    np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
    np.squeeze(scores),
    category_index,
    use_normalized_coordinates=True,
    line_thickness=8,
    min_score_thresh=0.85)

# All the results have been drawn on the frame, so it's time to display it.
cv2.imshow('Object detector', frame)
```

The following line is what id like to change, currently is feeding data from the webcam I want it to get this data from the image:

```
ret, frame = video.read()   <-- I want to change this line to read this data from the image
```

Can someone help me understand Rect and Frame and how I can assign this data from an image?

Answer (score 0):

ret, frame = video.read() is True if the frame is read correctly, this is the ret bit and frame is just one frame extracted from the video, which is an image. So it seems you are already classifying images from the video?

https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html

If you wanted to classify an image, such as a .jpg file saved in the same directory as your script you could use,

```
img = cv2.imread('img.jpg')
```

and then feed in an image that way.